# parent().parent().parent() - a better way?

Tags: jquery

I often use code like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".cChatSmileyWindow", $.proxy(function(e) {
    var windowID = $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().parent().data("windowid");
}, this));
```

Is there any nicer way to do this?
The HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="dropdownMenu dropdownArrowRight dropdownArrowBottom dropdownOpen" id="cChatSmileyBox1" data-windowid="1">
    <ul class="cChatSmileyList">
        <li>
            <span class="cChatSmileyListSmiley cChatSmileyWindow">
                <!-- ... -->
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

I tried `$(e.currentTarget).parent('dropdownMenu').data("windowid");` but it's not working.

Comment: $(e.currentTarget).parents('.dropdownMenu') is the right syntax to get to it

Comment: if you change `.parent('dropdownMenu')` to `.parents('.dropdownMenu')` it should work, assuming there is only one parent with .dropdownMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), you have to use `parents()`:

```
$(e.currentTarget).parents('dropdownMenu').first().data("windowid");
```

Answer (score 8):

Try closest():

```
var windowID = $(e.currentTarget).closest(".dropdownMenu").data("windowid");
```

Comment: I didn't even know this existed. Cool!

Comment: What happens if a element with the class `.dropdownMenu` is right beneath `.cChatSmileyWindow`?

Comment: .closest() looks only at ancestors..  If there is another one right beneath as a sibling, you would look for it using next().  "closest" does not mean physically closest.  It means closest ancestor.

Comment: Please read this to see difference between closest and parents: http://api.jquery.com/closest/  I still think you want closest for your problem as it goes directly to the first() element -- does a lot less work to get to the same answer.

Comment: I agree with David Fleeman, as he has said (and as in my answer below) parents() does more work and has the potential of returning more than one element.  Based on what you're trying to do, it would appear you only want to return a single element.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `$(e.currentTarget).parent('dropdownMenu').data("windowid");` doesn't work is because dropdownMenu isn't the parent.  Also, you're missing the period from the front of dropdownMenu but it wouldn't work anyway.

How about:

```
$(e.currentTarget).closest('.dropdownMenu').data("windowid")
```

I believe `closest()` will return a single element whereas `parents()` could return several.